# ¿Cómo evitar que el servidor de visual studio se detenga la compilación?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

estoy trabajando en una api en .NET Core 6, el problema es que cada vez que quiero elegir un archivo cualquiera para guardarlo en mi base de datos. Se abre el explorador de archivos, selecciono el archivo. Y se detiene la depuración de visual studio. No da ningún error, solo se cierra, se que el código no es el problema porque simplemente al dar clic en el archivo la api retorna un mensaje que dice "se subió un archivo" no hay ningún otro código.

alguien sabe en que parte se configura para evitar este tipo de problema??

Comment: Yo tuve un problema similar, en mi caso no tenia nada que ver con archivo.. Mi código llegaba a una parte y el visual studio detenía la depuración. Copiar todo a un proyecto nuevo (de cero), solucionó mi problema